# Cannot coerce array to object while Invoking Java method in Mule

Tags: mule4

I am trying to pass entire payload to my java class . This is my payload .

```
[
 {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "baseLoanAmount",
    "value": "10000.00"
 }
]
```

This is my java class

```
public void test(Object payload) {
    System.out.println("Inside Test  ******** "+payload);
}
```

In invoke i am calling the method like test(Object) and passing payload as argument. But i am getting an error saying Cannot coerce array to object . How i can pass it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes sense, because the parameter is an Object and the argument is an array. Try making the parameter an array, for example `test(Object[] payload)`.

Comment: i tried that , but no luck . Is there anything to do with the input argument definition . Error is like Cannot coerce Array
 {encoding...) to Object" evaluating expression: "payload".

Comment: Please add the complete error box text to the question.

Comment: Able to make it work when i am modifying input args as 
{
 
 arg0:payload
}